# Как отменить прозрачность?

Tags: html, css

Вот код: [jsfiddle.net/t5w9epr2/](http://jsfiddle.net/t5w9epr2/)

Как сделать так, чтобы текст не терял прозрачность, а был прозрачным только блок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8xhsy7q5/

для этого необходимо использовать background: rgba

почитайте это

http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/css-tricks/rgba

http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/color